# Nesting nodes in GraphViz

Tags: graphviz, graph-visualization

I'm trying to draw bigraphs in GraphViz (something like this)[image: Bigraph]

Is it possible to nest nodes directly in GraphViz?
If not is it possible to change the shape of a subgraph/cluster?

I have found a post about how to [import images of graphs into nodes](http://lists.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/2008q1/003871.html) but that seems like more effort than drawing them in powerpoint.

I can also make clusters visible, but they will include nodes from outside the cluster and as far as I can tell have a fixed shape.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Nest nodes is impossible**, but **nest clusters is possible**.
Subgraph/cluster has some predefined [styles](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/style/). Also nodes has predefines [shapes](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html). I don't know about manual editing path of border shapes for nodes in graphviz in different [`layout`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/layout/)s (or alternatives like representing the border as a chain of nodes), maybe someone else can tell us.

You **can get nested nodes** in [`neato`](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/neato/) layout engine, but in fact they will be **nested only visually**, because you just set their coordinates with `pos` attribute, which means they overlap each other.
Example image:
[image: overlapping nodes made with graphviz neato]
and script:

```
graph {
    layout=neato
    
    node [shape=circle pin=true ]
    
    foo [height=0.6 pos="0.7,1.5" ]
    bar [height=2 pos="1,2" ] 
    baz [height=1 pos="2,2" ]
}
```

You can import images as backgrounds into nodes as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382304/how-to-generate-nodes-with-customized-shape#answer-8392855). For example for Windows you can use [this official archive](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4207231/packages/generic/graphviz-releases/6.0.1/windows_10_msbuild_Release_graphviz-6.0.1-win32.zip), it comes with a `cairo.dll`, which will avoid errors like `Warning: No loadimage plugin for "jpeg:cairo"` when you run the command `$ dot -Tpng input.dot -o output.png`.

The image from your question can be drawn like this:
[image: bigraphs made with graphviz dot]
Script:

```
digraph {
    graph [
        layout=dot,
        ranksep=1,
        overlap=false,
        compound=true, // to enable `lhead`, `ltail` features
        newrank=true, // to enable ranking between nodes in clusters
        splines=true,
        splines=curved]
    edge[color=lime arrowhead=none]
    node[shape=plaintext]

    y0 [label=<<FONT><I>y</I><SUB>0</SUB></FONT>>]
    y1 [label=<<FONT><I>y</I><SUB>1</SUB></FONT>>]
    y2 [label=<<FONT><I>y</I><SUB>2</SUB></FONT>>]
    x0 [label=<<FONT><I>x</I><SUB>0</SUB></FONT>>]
    x1 [label=<<FONT><I>x</I><SUB>1</SUB></FONT>>]

    subgraph cluster_r0{
        style="rounded, dashed"
        margin=20
        label=<<FONT><I>r</I><SUB>0</SUB></FONT>>
        v2 [shape=circle]
        noname_dot[shape=point height=0]

        subgraph cluster_v0{
            style="rounded"
            label=<<FONT><I>v</I><SUB>0</SUB></FONT>>
            invis_dot_1 [style=invis shape=point]

            subgraph cluster_v1{
                style="rounded";
                label=<<FONT><I>v</I><SUB>1</SUB></FONT>>

                subgraph cluster_s0{
                    label=<<FONT><I>s</I><SUB>0</SUB></FONT>>
                    fillcolor=lightgrey
                    style="filled, rounded"
                    invis_dot_2 [style=invis shape=point]
                }
            }
        }
    }
  
    y0 -> noname_dot
    noname_dot -> invis_dot_2 [lhead="cluster_v1"]
    noname_dot -> invis_dot_1 [lhead="cluster_v0"]
    noname_dot -> v2 [constraint=false]
    y1 -> v2
    
    subgraph cluster_r1{
        style="rounded, dashed"
        margin=20
        label=<<FONT><I>r</I><SUB>1</SUB></FONT>>
        noname_dot_2 [shape=point height=0]

        subgraph cluster_s3{
            label=<<FONT><I>s</I><SUB>3</SUB></FONT>>
            fillcolor=lightgrey
            style="filled, rounded"
            invis_dot_s3 [style=invis shape=point]
        }
        subgraph cluster_v3{
            style="rounded"
            label=<<FONT><I>v</I><SUB>3</SUB></FONT>>

            subgraph cluster_s2{
                label=<<FONT><I>s</I><SUB>2</SUB></FONT>>
                fillcolor=lightgrey
                style="filled, rounded"
                invis_dot_s2 [style=invis shape=point]
            }
        }
    }
    
    y2 -> noname_dot_2
    noname_dot_2 -> x0  
    v2 -> noname_dot_2 [weight=0]
    noname_dot_2 -> invis_dot_s2 [lhead="cluster_v3"]
    invis_dot_s2 -> x1 [ltail="cluster_v3"]
 
    // Vertical alignment (`rank`) of the desired nodes:
    {rank=same; noname_dot; noname_dot_2; v2 }
    {rank=same; invis_dot_s3; invis_dot_s2 }
    {rank=same; x0; x1;}
    {rank=same; y0; y1; y2;}
}
```