# Graphviz: Nodes with custom Shapes

Tags: graphviz

I'm basically doing the same thing as in this question: [How to generate nodes with customized shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382304/how-to-generate-nodes-with-customized-shape?newreg=942e61c5e1544ece84d9c6948fc79c60), but I have problems with using eps / svg / other vector-based formats as images. I searched for the last two hours if there is any possibilty to scale eps file to the size that I wish, so that the nodes are about the same size as the normal shapes (box, rounded etc.).

- All attempts to scale the eps files with the width/height attribute failed and it seems like graphviz is ignoring that when using vector-based images.
- fixedsize=shape did also fail and the result is really strange with regards to where an edge's head ends up (somewhere in in the custom shape).

The only workaround (which sucks) is to set the size externally with tools like inkscape, or changing the fontsize to a value that all generated nodes scale more or less to the size of the custom shape. Is there any better way to do this, that I overlooked?

This is what I have so far:

```
digraph G {
rankdir="LR";
size="8.3,11.7";
page="8.3,11.7";
ratio="compress";
ranksep=0;
nodesep=0.5;
compound=true;
graph [ color=white, penwidth=0, labelloc="b" , margin=0];
node [fontsize=30];
bgcolor=white;
edge [arrowsize=1, color=black];

/* Nodes */
subgraph cluster_Computers {
    label="Comput";  Computers_icon [label="", image="gitrepo.eps",  shape=none,margin=0] ;};

Computers_icon -> c;

asdf -> jklö;
jklö -> Computers_icon;

c->f->g;
d->a->b;

d->g;
d->c;  
}
```